# When button is submit, PHP doesn't know

Tags: php, redirect, button, submit

```
    <html>
 <div class="panel-body">
                        <form method="post" action="index.php">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input class="form-control" placeholder="username" name="username" type="text" autofocus>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input class="form-control" placeholder="password" name="password" type="password" value="">
                            </div>
                            <input type='submit' name="submit" value='Login'>
                        </form>
                        <?php
                        if(isset($_POST['submit']))
                        {    
                            $username = sanitize($_POST['username']);
                            $password = sanitize($_POST['password']);
                            if($username && $password)
                            {
                                $query = mysql_query("SELECT Name, Password FROM users WHERE Name = '$username' LIMIT 1");
                                if(mysql_num_rows($query) == 1)
                                {
                                    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
                                    {
                                        $dbusername = $row['Name'];
                                        $dbpassword = $row['Password'];
                                    }
                                    $somename = hash( 'whirlpool', $password);
                                    $somename = strtoupper($somename);
                                    if($username == $dbusername && $somename == $dbpassword)
                                    {
                                        $_SESSION['username'] = $dbusername;
                                        header('location: /pcp/home.php');
                                    }
                                    else $error = "Wrong password!";
                                }
                                else $error =  "Username doesn't exist!";
                            }
                            else $error = "Type name and password!";
                        }
                        ?>
                    </div>
</html>
```

When I submit the button with correct password and user, it doesn't go to home.php but when I reload, it goes.

It's using bootstrap, is this the reason why? If so or not, could you help me fix it.

Comment: You will want to do all that code stuff before you output the page. Your `header()` can not be down in amongst html like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add your php code together with form elements, you need to write

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" >
```

or not. Simply separate form page & php page.
It means that

index.php

```
  <html>
 <div class="panel-body">
                        <form method="post" action="check.php">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input class="form-control" placeholder="username" name="username" type="text" autofocus>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input class="form-control" placeholder="password" name="password" type="password" value="">
                            </div>
                            <input type='submit' name="submit" value='Login'>
                        </form>

                    </div>
</html>
```

ckeck.php

```
               <?php
                if(isset($_POST['submit']))
                {    
                    $username = sanitize($_POST['username']);
                    $password = sanitize($_POST['password']);
                    if($username && $password)
                    {
                        $query = mysql_query("SELECT Name, Password FROM users WHERE Name = '$username' LIMIT 1");
                        if(mysql_num_rows($query) == 1)
                        {
                            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
                            {
                                $dbusername = $row['Name'];
                                $dbpassword = $row['Password'];
                            }
                            $somename = hash( 'whirlpool', $password);
                            $somename = strtoupper($somename);
                            if($username == $dbusername && $somename == $dbpassword)
                            {
                                $_SESSION['username'] = $dbusername;
                                header('location: /pcp/home.php');
                            }
                            else $error = "Wrong password!";
                        }
                        else $error =  "Username doesn't exist!";
                    }
                    else $error = "Type name and password!";
                }
                ?>
```